# Ubuntu 14.04 - rsync corrupting SSH configs/keys?

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keys

I have two Ubuntu 14.04 servers S1 (user root) and S2 (user dataman). S1 is responsible for handling file uploads and transferring backups to S2. On S1 I am using PubKey authentication to S2 for passwordless rsync.

I use a bash script to simplify the transfer (psuedo code):

```
while true
do
    for each file/folder in mydir/*; do
        rsync -aPs "${file}" dataman@S2:"${REMOTE_DIR}"
sleep 1
done
```

Now my results are really strange..

1. Redo key setup (because keys, or something, got corrupt)
2. Restart S1's transfer bash daemon (daemon runs as root)
3. Watch as it sync's one file successfully
4. It gets to another file, calls rsync, and fails (cannot SSH)

I go on S1 and `ssh dataman@S2` but it asks for a password. Weird.. So I go on S2 and see that in authorized_keys my pubkey exists from S1. it does. I verify the permissions of .ssh folder for both S1 and S2.. all good. Try ssh from S1 to S2 again.. still prompts for password.

I'm not sure how to debug this when I only have SSH access to both servers. I would run SSH in debug on S2 to see why S1 (with proper pubkey) isn't authenticating properly but I just dont have physical access.

Why would rsync affect any ssh configuration?

My sshd_config on S2:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I can replicate this easily, can anyone help?